# Magento 1.9 - Sanitization of Fields Required

Tags: magento-1.9, pci, vulnerability

I have to find PCI vulnerabilities in the Sanitization of fields. I have one form to submit data. In this, input fields of form should be sanitized.how to add a script for sanitization in magento1.9 for input text fields.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same way is working fine

```
        public function InputIntFilter($val)
         {   
       return filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        }
```